# Git push and commiter

Tags: git, security, gitlab

when I make a push to GIT (Gitlab) repo in the commits I see that commit has been made by user set in 'user.email' and 'user.name'.

Why does it happen? I think that information about user, should be taken from Gitlab profile.
Now it's possible to spoof our identification.

Comment: Check out [signed commits](https://git-scm.com/book/id/v2/Git-Tools-Signing-Your-Work). It prevents spoofing your identity in Git.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a few reasons that using an external identity source to rewrite author information isn't practical with Git:

1. Git is designed to be usable in a distributed environment, where there is no central server at all, and you can pull directly from other contributors' cloned repositories.  In this case, it's *necessary* to allow you to pass on commits that you did not create, and preserve author information.  Rewriting this information could cause data loss, where a developer passed commits on to you and then you tried to push them to Gitlab.  You didn't write them; Gitlab shouldn't assume that you did.  The Git model requires that you trust your peers not to lie to you about who wrote what.
2. Changing the author/committer information *changes the commit ID* and this would cause a large amount of unwanted branching, and severely confuse anyone who was trying to develop against this repository as their commits kept getting rewritten on the server any time they pushed.

Answer (score 4):

The answer by cdhowie (especially the 2nd point) addresses why it isn't done differently.  I would add for clarity that committer and author information are created by git - not by gitlab or any other hosting environment - when the commit is initially created in someone's local repository.  So gitlab-verified information wouldn't be available unless the developer happens to sync their local config with it, and if your concern is someone "spoofing" identities then obviously you don't trust the developer to do that.

But that leads to the real reason I decided to add an answer:  What I haven't seen anyone address is your concern about identity.  The committer and author name and email are *not*, and were never designed to be, a secure way of linking work to its creator.  If you need someone to vouch for a commit in a secure way, then you need to use signed commits.

Answer (score 1):

GitHub uses the email address in the commit header to link the commit to a GitHub user. If your commits are being linked to another user, or not linked to a user at all, you may need to change your local Git configuration settings, add an email address to your account email settings, or do both.
refer-->https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-commits-linked-to-the-wrong-user/